# Remove Expired Certificate

Tags: apex, visualforce, certification, certificates

Generated a new certificate however I do not have a way to remove the old expired certificate. 
The delete option is disabled and it appears I cannot deactivate the expired certificate either. 
We also continue to receive expired certificate warning emails despite having generated a new self signed certificate

Comment: Did you try opening a support ticket with SF?

Comment: @eric solved . Need to replace the one where it is using currently with a new one , Then you only will have an option to delete